# Programmatically update combinations in PrestaShop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to update product combinations price. `$c_key` is the combination ID, but it doesn't update the price.

```php
foreach ($c_area_input as $c_key => $c_area) {
    $price_c = (float)$c_price_area_input[$c_key] * (float)$c_area;
    $product->updateAttribute((int)$c_key,0, $price_c);
    Db::getInstance()->insert('areapacks_combination', array(
        'id_product' => (int)$id_product,
        'id_combination' => (int)$c_key,
        'item_area' => (float)$c_area,
        'price_item_area' => (float)$c_price_area_input[$c_key]
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with :

```
foreach ($c_area_input as $c_key => $c_area) {
    $price_c = (float)$c_price_area_input[$c_key] * (float)$c_area;

    $product = new Product($id_product);
    $product->updateProductAttribute($c_key, $c_price_area_input[$c_key], $c_price_area_input[$c_key]);
}
```